# Template function with a forward declared class

Tags: c++, templates

Noob question here. I have a class with a circular dependency so I forward declared it. Now, I'm planning to try out a template with this.

//in C.h

```
class C {
public:
  virtual void getMap();
}
```

// in A.h

```
    class C;
    class A {
    public:
       virtual void foo(C *c);

    template <class T>     
       void changeProperty(C *c, string& s) {
          void* obj = c->getMap()->at(s); // does not compile 
          // (did not include the rest for brevity)
       }
    }
```

This fails to compile at the line specified stating that Class C doesn't have a function 'getMap()'. Can this be fixed? If so, how?

Comment: This is the reason why you don't define functions in the header file but do it in the source file (.cpp)

Comment: I thought template functions were different and had to be defined in the header. That's what most examples showed. I guess I got it wrong.

Comment: Yes sry. You can not have the source in a different file. But You can still define it further down in the header.

Comment: I believe you can. I put the definition in the C.cpp file, and it compiles.

Comment: Beats me. Well good luck with whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the definition of `changeProperty` out of the class (so it's not `inline`) and place it somewhere after the definition of `class C` has been seen.

So the preprocessed result will end up as something like:

```
class C;
class A {
public:
   virtual void foo(C *c);

template <class T>     
   void changeProperty(C *c, string& s);
}

// ...

class C {
public:
  virtual void getMap();
}

// ...

template <class T>     
   void A::changeProperty(C *c, string& s)
   {
      void* obj = c->getMap()->at(s); // compiles
      // (did not include the rest for brevity)
   }
```

Comment: @PeterWood, it's not relevant to the circular dependency problem so let's assume that was an unintentional typo in the OP's example. Otherwise if we're going to be pedantic I'd point out there's no circular reference because `C` doesn't mention `A`, but I assume in the OP's real code it does